# Unset/Delete a custom property/CSS variable

Tags: html, css, css-variables

Take the following example:

```css
.article, .note {
    color: var(--text-color, red);
 }
 .theme {
    --text-color: blue;
 }
 .theme .note {
     --text-color: unset;
 }
```

```html
<section>
    <p class="article">Article</p>
    <p class="note">Note</p>
</section>
<section class="theme">
    <p class="article">Article</p>
    <p class="note">Note</p>
</section>
```

Is it possible to make the second "Note" red again by unsetting the CSS variable?

I know that I could apply the CSS variable only to `.article` but assume I have a lot of similar elements where I want the theme applied but only a few exemptions. Then maintaining the selector would be rather tedious.

I could change the theme selector to `.theme :not(.note)` but that does not work on any `.note` elements nested in other elements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the value `initial`, since IE [doesn't](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) support [CSS vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) it is not an issue using `initial` here (also IE [doesn't support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value))

```css
.article,
.note {
  color: var(--text-color, red);
}

.theme {
  --text-color: blue;
}

.theme .note {
  --text-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p class="article">Article</p>
  <p class="note">Note</p>
</section>
<section class="theme">
  <p class="article">Article</p>
  <p class="note">Note</p>
</section>
```