# Is there a way to declare css custom properties without a value?

Tags: css, css-variables

I want to create a component and expose certain properties that could be overridden by parent elements.

I want those properties to be *declared* on top of the CSS class declaration so that they can be read at a quick glance, similar to how we read a function signature in programming.

Here's an example. Let's say I'm creating a button which has its own colors, but allows to change its background color if there's a `--button-bg-color` defined:

```
.my-button {
  --bg-color: blue;

  /* lots of other css... */

  /**
    * here I assume that there might be a --button-bg-color defined,
    * but I have a fallback to my own --bg-color variable
    */
  background-color: var(--button-bg-color, var(--bg-color));
}
```

The problem with the code above is that the `--button-bg-color` variable is referenced somewhere deep down the styling.

What I wish I could do is the declare somewhere up top that I might want to use this variable. This would tell me that this component expects to be overridden. But I need to declare it in such a way that doesn't *set* any value for the variable. This is purely about structure and intent.

Maybe something like this?

```
.my-button {
  /* Ideally, declare variable without referencing any values */
  --button-bg-color; /* no value set, but this means the propery will used later on in this class declaration */

  /* Or perhaps there is something like undefined? */
  --button-bg-color: undefined;
 
  --bg-color: blue;
 
  /* the rest of the code is the same */
}
```

Comment: Falsy values of all color properties is none.

Comment: It doesn't look like a falsy value in a sense that the fallback is not used if `none` is the first argument of `var()`. Just tried it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unset/Delete a custom property/CSS variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830373/unset-delete-a-custom-property-css-variable)

Comment: @vsync It doesn't, my question is about declarting a custom-property on top of the css declaration and not about resetting regular css properties

Comment: You can just add those in your documentation file or as code comment since they are useless. There are other ways to achieve the desired goal of letting others know about those variables

Comment: Creating correctly-named variables is much more powerful than using code comments. Comments get stale, variables is what people actually read during refactorings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh well, I just realized that we can do this:

```
.my-button {
  --bg-color: var(--button-bg-color, blue); /* inherit with fallback */

  /* lots of other css... */
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

This way there's also less repetition.

Comment: This is actually the idiomatic (in other words, ideal) approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this question searching for something a bit different. I think someone might find it useful. **If you really need to reset some custom property back to undefined. Here is how to do it:**

```
.my-button {
  --bg-color: var(--button-bg-color, blue);
}
.theme-1 {
  --button-bg-color: red;
}
.reset-bg-color {
  --button-bg-color: initial
}
```

So when applying just .theme-1 the button would be red, but applying both classes resets --button-bg-color back to undefined, and the fallback to blue works again.

Edit:
Just found out you can use *initial* keyword. It seems to work the same. Original solutin was to set it to any undefind var. Ex: var(--undefined).